# What's the difference between vel, aut, -ve, et cetera?

Tags: classical-latin, conjunction, vocabulary, meaning

So I see "vel", "aut", and "-ve" being used (mostly) interchangeably in the Latin I read. Is there any idiomatic difference, or can they be used interchangeably?

For example, is it valid Latin (and does it have the right meaning) if I use "-ve" for either/or, like I would with "aut"?

> Licet tibi habere **aut** vim **aut** laetitia
>
> Licet tibi habere vim**ve** laetitia**ve**

And does using "vel" instead of "aut" change the meaning in any way?

> Licet tibi habere **vel** vim **vel** laetitia

Comment: When I read the title I kept thinking that there is a big difference between aut, vel, and -ve versus et cetera.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply, vel is inclusive and aut is exclusive. As [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3atext%3a1999.04.0059) put it:

> In general *aut* puts in the place of a previous assertion another, objectively and absolutely antithetical to it, while vel indicates that the contrast rests upon subjective opinion or choice; i. e. aut is objective, vel subjective, or aut excludes one term, vel makes the two indifferent.

&

> [Vel] As disjunctive conjunction, to introduce an alternative as a matter of choice or preference, or as not affecting the principal assertion (while *aut* introduces an absolute or essential opposition...

Going off your examples:

> Licet tibi habere aut vim aut laetitiam.

This means, "You are allowed to have either power or happiness **but not both**."

> Licet tibi habere vel vim vel laetitiam.

"You are allowed to have power, or perhaps happiness, *or both*, should you wish."

The enclitic *-ve* is the same as *vel*.

Bennett's [example](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect341) I think is more illustrative:

> **quī aethēr vel caelum nōminātur**, *which is called aether or heaven*

That is, both *aether* and *caelum* as the name for the sky is correct.

So in your example, *aut* is the best word to use.

Answer (score 11):

I'll just add that there's another word for "or," *sive* (or *seu*). It's used to mean "also known as" or to indicate that the speaker is indifferent as to which option is chosen.

> Si media nox est sive est prima vespera . . .
> Tamen est eundum quo imperant.
>
> Whether it's the middle of the night or early evening . . .
> Still, you have to go where they order you.
>
> Plautus *Curculio* 1.1

I always feel kind of bad for *sive*, as if it were the redheaded stepchild of disjunctions.

Comment: _sive_, a contraction of _si_ and _vi_, means "or if". It's not really synonymous with _vel_.

Comment: I'm confused—isn't that exactly what this answer says?

Comment: "*media nox*" isn't another word for "*prima vespera*". I don't see how you could use "*vel*" in your example.

Comment: @Geremia *Sive* often means simply "or" in Late Latin texts, especially to indicate a subtitle of a book or another name for something. See section C under Lewis and Short.

Comment: @cmw Yes, L&S §C of "[_sive_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sive&la=la#lexicon)" says it's disjunctive, but interestingly it says _vel_ was sometimes used in a "purely disjunctive sense," so there is some evolution in these "or" words.

Comment: @Geremia Yep, very true.