# What is the difference between "ac" (or "atque") and "et"?

Tags: word-comparison, conjunction

What is the difference between *ac* (or *atque*) and *et*? And how do I know when to use *atque* instead of just *ac*?

It seems that *ac* "binds more tightly" than *et*. Is this true? Or is the difference between *ac* (or *atque*) and *et* the conjunctive analogue of [the difference between *vel* and *aut*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/73/576)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Atque*, [according to L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=atque&la=la#lexicon), means

> a copulative particle, *and also*, *and besides*, *and even*, *and*

According to [Bennett's *New Latin Grammar* ch. 6 §"Coordinate Conjunctions"](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/15665/15665-h/15665-h.htm#sect341), "*atque* is used before vowels and consonants; *ac* never before vowels, and seldom before *c*, *g*, *qu*."

[L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=atque&la=la#lexicon) continue, saying that *atque*

> indicat[es] a close internal connection between single words or whole clauses; while *et* designates an external connection of diff. objects with each other

So, it seems these would make sense:

> mulier ***ac*** mater
> (a woman *and also* a mother ← related)

and

> pater ***et*** arbor
> (a father *and* a tree ← unrelated)

Bennett also mentions that *-que* binds more tightly than *atque*.

It seems this analogy would hold:

**[*vel* : *aut*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/73/576) :: *atque* : *et***

"inclusive disjunction" : "exclusive disjunction" :: "inclusive conjunction" : "exclusive conjunction"

---

As I mention in [my comment here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/40/whats-the-difference-between-vel-aut-ve-et-cetera/73#comment7674_278), *L&S* §C of "[***sive***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sive&la=la#lexicon)/***seu***" says it's disjunctive.

(Interestingly, [*L&S*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sive&la=la#lexicon) also says *vel* was sometimes used in a "purely disjunctive sense," so there is some evolution in these "or" words.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a long and very thorough explanation under ‘and’ in Smith & Hall’s *Copious & Critical English-Latin Dictionary*, which is readily available in various forms. (The authors also refer the reader to Allen’s *Doctrina Cop. Ling. Latinae*, which I have not been able to trace, but is probably 19th century and available in specialised academic libraries.)

Comment: Correction: Allen's can be downloaded at https://archive.org/details/doctrinacopularu00alle

Comment: can you try to distill that explanation into an answer?

Comment: _Doctrina copularum linguæ latinæ_: very neat. I didn't know a whole book was written on the subject. thank you

Comment: Smith and Hall's explanation can be found online on Latinitium: https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh962