# ἤ = vel or ἤ = aut?

Tags: word-comparison, ancient-greek, conjunction

[*LSJ*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%B7#lexicon) says [ἤ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%B7#lexicon) is a "disjunctive *or*", but does it correspond Latin's [*vel* ("inclusive disjunction") or *aut* ("exclusive disjunction")](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1378/576)?

Comment: No time to write an answer at the moment but I believe ἤ corresponds to *aut*, while *vel* is expressed by εἴτε.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ἤ corresponds to Latin's *aut* (exclusive disjunction). St. Jerome uses *aut* to translate ἤ in [Mt. 19:25](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=19&l=29-#x).

[Εἴτε](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%B5%E1%BC%B4%CF%84%CE%B5#lexicon) corresponds to Latin's *vel* (inclusive disjuction).