# generatio = childbirth or also education/raising of children?

Tags: vocabulary

*Generatio* means "a begetting", but does that include the whole process of conceiving, bearing, birthing, and educating the child?

Answer (score 1):

[St. Thomas Aquinas says](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age?results.pageSize=50&text=%3DGeneratio%20%3F1%20*1%20%3Deducatio) "*generatio [**et**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1378/576) educatio*". The fact he uses the exclusive conjunction *et* and not the inclusive conjunction *ac*/*atque* shows that he considers *generatio* not to be synonymous with *educatio*. Thus, *generatio* is the process of procreating a child, and *educatio* is the process of raising the born child.

Comment: That jibes with my experience. I've read *generatio* as meaning begetting, bearing, and birthing, but not as educating.