Shouldn't this est be a sunt in this sentence?
This is a famous quote from Cicero:

Num unum diem postea L. Saturninum tribunum plebis et C.Servilium praetorem mors ac reipublicae poena remorata est?

The verb remorari is deponent, so the subjects of the phrase are supposed to be mors and reipublicae poena. As we have two subjects, I suppose the verb should be in plural right? Why is it in singular?

"ac" does not mean just "and." A preposition like "cum" (one etymology is ad+que), it behaves subordinatingly and not coordinatingly. It is more like "as well as," "that is at the same time the," and "i.e.": https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1371/11407

The use of a singular verb, "remorata est"--"(it is) delayed", is because of the compounded subject, "mors ac reipublicae poena", being treated as a single concept. In Latin, plurals are not so clear-cut as they are in English; and, it is common to use a singular verb when multiple subjects are closely-related or represent a unified idea. Therefore, even though there are two distinct elements ("death & punishment"), they are considered together as a single event.

English works like this, too; e.g. "Breaking and entering is a felony."

@Ben Kovitz: Is "breaking-and-entering" hyphenated, making it one unit?

@tony It doesn't matter - if they're considered as a unit, the verb is singular. Compare "Inviting someone to your house and killing them is frowned on" vs "Inviting someone to your house and killing them are frowned on" - the latter conveys the impression that merely inviting someone to your house is frowned on, which in general it isn't.
