# Does the abbreviation “ſ.” in this 1755 work mean “sine”?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, abbreviations, medicine, germanic, alchemy

For [an answer on the RPG Stack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/193128/4563), I’m trying to read some entries in [*Medicinisch-Chymisch und Alchemistisches Oraculum*](https://archive.org/details/b30522535/mode/2up), a 1755 German work whose entries are in Latin. I’m stuck on these two entries:

1. [image: “Acetum ſ. vinum mortuum” next to a cross shape] on page 1
2. [image: “Vinum mortuum, ſ. acetum” next to three symbols separated by commas] on page 33

My first thought here was “Latin word order doesn’t matter,” so no matter what “ſ.” means, this is the same four words and mean the same thing. Then someone pointed out that “ſ.” might be short for *sine*, in which case it would matter. I can’t for the life of me find any examples of “ſine,” much less abbreviated to “ſ.,” but it seems plausible. This is backed up by other entries of “Aurum, sol,” and “Sol, ſ. aurum,” where the expected symbol for both gold and the Sun (enshrined in Unicode as `U+2609` ☉) is found (among others) under “Aurum, sol,” and “Sol, ſ. aurum” has more unusual symbols (that I guess refer only to the Sun and not to gold).

So is “ſ.” understood here to mean “sine”?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look closely, you will note that the 's' is in [blackletter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter) script. According to long-standing German printing tradition, German words are in blackletter, Latin words in Antiqua.

The German word that 's' stands for, as in virtually every German lexicon or reference work, is "siehe," which means "see" (like 'cf' in English). In other words, it is a pointer to another entry, which the reader is encouraged to also read. It does not generally suggest that the words mean the same.

Comment: By the way, in other entries, "siehe" is written out.

Comment: I _had_ noticed that the font seemed a bit different, interesting. Really appreciate this, it feels much more plausible to me than the claim of “sive,” so +1 for that. On the other hand, it still does not tell me what distinction the author was drawing between “acetum” and “vinum mortuum,” though I suppose that might just be unknown.

Comment: @KRyan He translates both as "Essig" (vinegar), so probably his opinion is that they mean the same.

Comment: I just noticed that, indeed. Bizarre choice then. Even if you were including duplicate entries for the sake of someone who looked up either term, you’d think you’d include the complete list in each place, particularly considering it’s only 4 symbols (1 line) total.

Comment: Not Latin at all then! Incredible.

Comment: Although, interestingly enough, if they're both translated as *Essig*, than the German *siehe* here could have been substituted with *sive* with no real change in meaning.

Comment: @cmw Unless the author felt there was some distinction that was just lost in translation to German—but that distinction wasn’t important enough to capture, I guess? Anyway, ſiehe makes much more sense than sive for some of the other entries, such as “aurum, sol” vs. “sol, ſ. aurum,” since alchemists often used the same symbols for both the Sun and gold—but some symbols meant only one of the two, so the “sol, ſ. aurum” entry is “symbols that mean ‘sol’ _only_, but remember a lot of symbols could mean gold or sun and those are under ‘aurum’.” At least, this is my suspicion.

Comment: Pet peeve: "cf." is NOT synonymous to "see". It should only be used for comparative purposes.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I read this answer as saying that “siehe” means “see,” but at least in this context is used to mean specifically “check this for comparison,” very much as “cf.” is used. So the parenthetical here is further defining the meaning of the word, not simply restating it in other language, not making the claim that “see” and “cf.” are synonymous.

Comment: @KRyan - "acetum" is clearly related to "acetic acid", referring to the chemical composition of vinegar.  afaict "vinum mortuum" translates literally as "dead wine", referring to the manufacturing process for vinegar.

Comment: @TimSparkles Both phrases are translated as simply “vinegar” in every source I can find—including this work itself, where both are “Eſſig,” German for vinegar. I can speculate plenty of distinctions that the author _could have_ meant, but what I actually want is some documentation backing up a claim that a particular distinction _actually is_ the one the author meant.

Answer (score 7):

The "long s" is an abbreviation for "sive" ("or"). The author is giving two alternative names for "vinegar".

Comment: I’m going to need to see some kind of evidence for that, because while it’s entirely possible that the author just messed up an included two separate entries for the same thing, it seems hard to just assume that.

Comment: "Sine"  would be followed by a noun in the ablative case. "Acetum" and "vinum" are in the nominative.

Comment: @KRyan Cf. [this thread and its comments](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/278/78). It's a very standard abbreviation.

Comment: @KRyan, it's arguably not just two separate entries for the _same thing_ if they're synonyms and the editor expects the user/reader to look for either form in a glossary. FWIW it also makes perfect sense to me the _sive_ reading. Moreover, dead wine, and fermented/expired wine (i.e., vinegar) look very close in meaning.

Comment: @Rafael If the two entries were the same aside from the ordering/alphabetizing, yes, it would make sense. But the author lists _different symbols_ under each version, implying that “acetum ſ. vinum mortuum” and “vinum mortuum, ſ. acetum” refer to different things in the author’s mind. Perhaps the author just made a mistake, but I still find that very hard to believe since one would expect that if he had forgotten that he’d already done “acetum ſ. vinum mortuum,” he would include (at least some of) the same symbols under “vinum mortuum, ſ. acetum.” There is no overlap.

Comment: @KRyan, good point

Comment: @KRyan But note that in both cases the German equivalent is _Essig_ (i.e., vinegar). I still find plausible that the lack of overlapping is simply due to a pre-scientific accuracy standard for the text.